# UITableView not reloading data when SearchBar is Canceled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller, reloaddata

I have a SearchBar on my tableView. It is correctly working when typing to search through the table view. However, when the cancel button is pressed, the tableView is not reloading the data.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    isFiltered = false;
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]
     initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
  
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    
    self.files  = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:@"thepdfpowerpoints"];
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [self.files objectAtIndex:thepath.row];
    self.title = @"Devo Songs";
    self.filenames = [[documentsDirectoryPath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    
    
    NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.files count]];
    for (NSString *path in self.files) {
        [names addObject:[[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
    }
    //self.files = names;
    self.files = [names sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSLog(@"FILESLOAD%@", self.files);

     self.tableView.delegate = self;
       self.tableView.dataSource = self;
      }
-(void) updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    isFiltered = true;
    NSString *searchText = self.searchController.searchBar.text;

           searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
           
           for (NSString *file in self.files) {
               NSRange nameRange = [file rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
               if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                   [searchResults addObject:file];
               }
           }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void) searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    //self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
   NSLog(@"Cancel");
   isFiltered=false;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    
}
```

I have added an NSLog in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` This is showing in console when I first go to the view, but it is not being called when I click the cancel button.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSLog(@"Loading");
```

The code for number of rows/section is:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    if (isFiltered) {
        return [searchResults count];
        
    }
    else {
        return [self.files count];
    }
    
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    
    return 1;
    
    
}
```

Comment: Is `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:` called? What's the code for numberOrRow/numberOfSection? Are you using there `isFiltered`?

Comment: @Larme I updated the OP with that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tapping the search bar's "Cancel" button clears the search text...

***and then calls*** `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`.

So your current code is setting `isFiltered` to true again, and then reloading the table view based on an empty `searchResults` array.

You don't really need to implement `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` unless you want to do something other than refresh your table view.

Try changing your `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` method to this - it will use the full `files` array if no text has been entered in the search field. Otherwise, it will filter the files array.

```
-(void) updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    NSLog(@"update"); // just to show when this is being called

    NSString *searchText = self.searchController.searchBar.text;

    if (searchText.length != 0) {
        isFiltered = YES;
        
        searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        for (NSString *file in self.files) {
            NSRange nameRange = [file rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                [searchResults addObject:file];
            }
        }
    } else {
        isFiltered = NO;
    }
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```